# Changing a div attribute using a function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am not sure why my move function, is not changing the style.left or style.top attributes of my 'toy'

Any tips, or general information/links on how to animate a div?  I'm pulling my hair out over here. :)

```js
var ref;
var timer;
var velocity = 50;
var deltaX = 5;
var deltaY = 5;
var left = 0;
var top = 0;
//var moveX = math.random() * velocity;
//var moveY = math.random() * velocity;

function init() {
  alert("in init fucntion");
  ref = document.getElementById("toy");
  alert("ref = " + ref.valueOf());
  timer = setInterval(move, 50);
}

function move() {
  alert("called move");
  var left = parseInt(ref.style.left);
  var top = parseInt(ref.style.top);
  alert("left = " + left.valueOf() + " top = " + top.valueOf());

  left += 5;
  top += 5;
  alert("left =" + left.valueOf() + "top = " + top.valueOf());

  ref.style.left += left;
  ref.style.top += 5;
  alert("ref.style.left = " + ref.style.left.valueOf() + " ref.style.top = " + ref.style.top.valueOf());

  ref.style.left = (left + deltaX) % posEnd;

}

var posEnd = 0;
var objWidth = 100;

if (window.innerWidth) {
  posEnd = window.innerWidth
} else if (window.document.body.clientWidth) {
  posEnd = window.document.body.clientWidth
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">

  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="toy">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/mouse_clip_art_6054.jpg" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: What *is* happening and what did you *expect* to see? Could you convert your code into a stack snippet so that everybody could see how it works?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want use css3 animations? I recommend to use css3 animations since you only have to change the left attribute once and the webbrowser animates the div for you. But in some situations you might want to look at a javascript solution like the one you're trying now.

Comment: Where is `posEnd` defined?

Comment: You have `posEnd` defined as `0` and then you have `left + deltaX) % posEnd;`. Anything `% 0` is `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the units the position is in. For example, `style.left = 10` won't work - you need `style.left = '10px'`;

Here is a slightly simplified version of your `move()` function showing this:

```
function move() {
    var left = parseInt(ref.style.left);
    var top = parseInt(ref.style.top);

    left += 5;
    top += 5;

    ref.style.left = left + 'px';
    ref.style.top = top + 'px';
}
```

And a fully working snippet:

```js
var ref;
var timer;
var velocity = 50;
var deltaX = 5;
var deltaY = 5;
var left = 0;
var top = 0;

function init() {
  ref = document.getElementById("toy");
  timer = setInterval(move, 500);
}

function move() {
  var left = parseInt(ref.style.left);
  var top = parseInt(ref.style.top);

  left += 5;
  top += 5;

  ref.style.left = left + 'px';
  ref.style.top = top + 'px';
}

var posEnd = 0;
var objWidth = 100;

if (window.innerWidth) {
  posEnd = window.innerWidth
} else if (window.document.body.clientWidth) {
  posEnd = window.document.body.clientWidth
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="init()">

  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="toy">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/mouse_clip_art_6054.jpg" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```